# how to start and stop ec2 instances using php aws sdk

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

pretty new with the aws sdk, looking to start. i've installed the sdk and everything but how do I start the ec2 instances using the php sdk? Some code samples would really be useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a basic example of starting a machine from a defined AMI:

```
$image_id  = 'ami-3d4ff254'; //Ubuntu 12.04
$min       = 1;              //the minimum number of instances to start
$max       = 1;              //the maximum number of instances to start
$options   = array(
    'SecurityGroupId' => 'default',  //replace with your security group id
    'InstanceType'    => 't1.micro',
    'KeyName'         => 'keypair',  //the name of your keypair for auth
    'InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior' => 'terminate' //terminate on shutdown
);

require_once('AWSSDKforPHP/sdk.class.php');

$ec2 = new AmazonEC2();

$response = $ec2->run_instances($image_id, $min, $max, $options);

if(!$response->isOK()){
    echo "Start failed\n";
}
```

This is assuming you have your AWS credentials setup properly ... Hopefully this gets you pointed in the right direction ...

Comment: Thank you for this useful code. Is it possible to start an existing instance? I can't seem to find this information.

Comment: @SSHThis try startInstances

Comment: It's actually "start_instances" http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/#m=AmazonEC2/start_instances

Comment: Does the $response contain the public IP of the instance?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a more detailed script if you are interested:

```
// Sleep time to allow EC2 instance to start up
$sleeptime = 15;
$username = "ec2-user";

// For AWS PHP SDK
putenv('HOME=/home/ec2-user/');
require_once 'AWSSDKforPHP/sdk.class.php';

// Get data from HTTP POST
$ami = $_POST['amis'];
$instancetype = $_POST['instancetype'];
$keyname = $_POST['key'];
$securitygroup = $_POST['securitygroups'];

// Instantiate the AmazonEC2 class
$ec2 = new AmazonEC2();

// Boot an instance of the image
$response = $ec2->run_instances($ami, 1, 1, array(
    'KeyName' => $keyname,
    'InstanceType' => $instancetype,
    'SecurityGroupId' => $securitygroup,
));
if (!($response->isOK())) {
    echo "<p class='error'>ERROR! Could not create new instance!</p>";
    return; 
}
$instance = $response->body->instancesSet->item->instanceId;
$message = "<p>Your instance has been successfully created.</p>";
$message .= ("<p>Instance ID is: <b>$instance</b></p>");

// Give instance some time to start up
sleep ($sleeptime);

// Get the hostname from a call to the DescribeImages operation.
$response = $ec2->describe_instances(array(
    'Filter' => array(
       array('Name' => 'instance-id', 'Value' => "$instance"),
    )
));
if (!($response->isOK())) {
    echo "<p class='error'>ERROR! Could not retrieve hostname for instance!</p>";
    return; 
}
$hostname = $response->body->reservationSet->item->instancesSet->item->dnsName;

// Output the message
$message .= "<p>Your instance hostname is: <b>$hostname</b></p>";
$message .= "<p>You can connect to your instance using this command:<br>" .
    "<b>ssh -i $keyname.pem $username@" . $hostname .  "</b></p>";

echo $message;
```

Pretty much the same as @dleiftah's, except that it outputs the hostname of the new instance upon completion.

Comment: But How can I stop this instance with sdk?

Comment: To stop instance, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Aws.Ec2.Ec2Client.html#_stopInstances  click to expand Basic Formatting example, so the code is $client->stopInstances()